# onclick event with PHP SESSION variable happening on every page load

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, logout

I'm trying to implement a logout mechanism, which would consist of a link to click that should set a SESSION variable to True, send the user to the login page where PHP will check the value of the same variable and destroy the cookie before regenerating the session if it's set to true. The problem is that what should happen as an onclick event happens every time I load the page (And I can confirm this by echoing the variable at the top of the page, which returns always 1) except for the first time, where instead I get an error message because the variable is still not set. Here's my code:

JavaScript:

```
<script>
function destroy_session(){
    <?php $_SESSION["Logout"]=True; ?>
}
document.getElementById("logout").onclick=destroy_session;
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<li><a href="../index.php" id="logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
```

PHP:

```
if ($_SESSION['Logout']){
    session_unset();     
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: your code is impossible. php runs on the server, and your little php-inside-js will have executed WHEN THE PAGE WAS GENERATED. you cannot do this as-is. you are simply unconditionally setting Logout to true, regardless of whether the user clicks that logout link or not.

Comment: Is there a way to do what I want to do with session variables then? Taking into consideration what you just wrote the only thing I can think of is sending the user back to the login page and appending a GET variable to the header to destroy the session.

Comment: you can do whatever you want with your session varaibles. but to CHANGE those session variables in the way you want, you need to make an ajax call, or do a full-blown server round-trip and rebuild the page.

Comment: You could just have the Logout button redirect the user to a logout.php page that simply handles the logout process without any actual html to render. Then after the logout logic is done, just redirect wherever you want.

Comment: Make your life easier – and don’t use JavaScript here; instead, just call your index script with a parameter, such as `index.php?logout=true`. Then, in your script, check if that parameter is set, and if so, destroy the session there/remove the indicator that the user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

js:

```
function profile_logout(){
    $('#response').html("Please wait...");

     $.post( "/logout.php", function( data ) {    
                 $('#response').html(data);    
      });

        return false;
 }
```

html:

```
<li id="response"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="profile_logout();"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
```

logout.php:

```
<?php

@session_start();

session_unset();
session_destroy();

echo "Logout success !";

?>
```

Note: don't forget add library jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

this is for example :)